# S3 gives access denied for URL with non encoded query parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public image in an S3 bucket.

The issue is I can only access the URL with the encoded query parameters:

```
https://glue-s3-bucket-2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/users/images/b4a24058-1e99-4cd8-b9b0-6749aecfdff8.jpg%3Fdate%3D1621271637169
```

While if I try to access it with decoded query parameters I get access denied:

```
https://glue-s3-bucket-2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/users/images/b4a24058-1e99-4cd8-b9b0-6749aecfdff8.jpg?date=1621271637169
```

In S3:
the S3 URI shows:
`s3://glue-s3-bucket-2/image.jpg?date=1620831587318`

the key is `image.jpg?date=1620831587318`

and the Object Url:
`https://glue-s3-bucket-2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/image.jpg%3Fdate%3D1620831587318`

Is it an encoding issue when saving the file or is it a permission issue in AWS?

Comment: In your first example, those are not query params, the "?date=1620831587318" is part of object name. Your second example doesn't work because you are requesting the object "b4a24058-1e99-4cd8-b9b0-6749aecfdff8.jpg" instead of its actual name "b4a24058-1e99-4cd8-b9b0-6749aecfdff8.jpg?date=1620831587318"

Comment: Probably not the best idea to bind the timestamp into the object key like that.

Comment: ah, thanks. I think I understand the issue. I guess I need to make sure the file encoded properly when I save it so, the `params` don't become part of name